# How to retrieve data from google sign in button after success?

Tags: android, google-account

I have created Google sign in button to get access through the Google account into my app.

I have no thought about how to **retrieve the information of Google account and store it into my sqlitedB of the app**.

So can any one have a suggestion please let me know.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **GoogleSignInResult.getSignInAccount** method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.

```
 GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
 GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
 String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
 String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
 String personId = acct.getId();
 Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

more details refer [Retrieve profile information for a signed-in user](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people)

Comment: Thank you very much +sasikumar